# Dynamic pictures on a Userform in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

This Code works fine when i step through the code with F8, and i can se the picture. But when i run the code the picture is just a white fore color. The image size changes but doesn't show the actual picture. I've changed the code to get the actual image on to the user form. This was the first code i made that worked without throwing a fault. I have a few pictures on the sheet ICONS and their names are listed in column A from row 2 and down on that sheet. The pictures are in gif and png format.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    ' Hämta det valda registret och ikonen från UserFormen
    Dim valtRegister As String
    Dim valtIcon As String
    Dim valtSkala As Double
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 8
        If Controls("OptionButton" & i).Value = True Then
            If i = 1 Then
                valtRegister = "Flik 1-5"
                valtSkala = 0.5
            End If
            If i = 2 Then
                valtRegister = "Flik 1-10"
                valtSkala = 0.5
            End If
            If i = 3 Then
                valtRegister = "Flik 1-15"
                valtSkala = 1
            End If
            If i = 4 Then
                valtRegister = "Flik 1-20"
                valtSkala = 1
            End If
            If i = 5 Then
                valtRegister = "Flik 1-31"
                valtSkala = 1
            End If
            If i = 6 Then
                valtRegister = "Flik A-Ö"
                valtSkala = 1
            End If
            If i = 7 Then
                valtRegister = "Flik 1-12"
                valtSkala = 1.3
            End If
            If i = 8 Then
                valtRegister = "Flik Jan-Dec"
                valtSkala = 1.3
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    If valtRegister = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vänligen välj ett register.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    valtIcon = cmbIcon.Value
    
    If valtIcon = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vänligen välj en ikon från listan.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Kontrollera om det valda bladet finns
    If BladFinns(valtRegister) Then
        Worksheets(valtRegister).Visible = True
        If Worksheets("Flik Jan-Dec").Visible = True And Not valtRegister = "Flik Jan-Dec" Then Worksheets("Flik Jan-Dec").Visible = False
        ' Infoga ikonen på det valda bladet
        InfogaIcon valtRegister, valtIcon, valtSkala
    Else
        MsgBox "Registeret '" & valtRegister & "' finns inte!", vbExclamation
    End If
    
    Unload Me ' Stäng UserFormen efter att ha klickat på OK
End Sub

Private Sub cmbIcon_Change()
    Dim lItem As Long
    For lItem = 0 To cmbIcon.ListCount - 1
        If cmbIcon.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            Call Pict(lItem)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub Pict(n)
    Dim Ans As String
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim Pth As String
    Dim Pic As Object

    Dim Strpath As String ' Lägg till denna deklaration

    Set Pic = Sheets("ICONS").Shapes(cmbIcon.List(n))
    Pic.Copy 'Picture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    Strpath = AdresseLocal(ThisWorkbook.Path) & "\Temp.jpg"
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100, 0, Pic.Width, Pic.Height)
    cht.Chart.Paste
    cht.Chart.Export Strpath
    cht.Delete
    Set cht = Nothing
    Me.imgBild.Picture = LoadPicture(Strpath)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAvbryt_Click()
    Unload Me ' Stäng UserFormen efter att ha klickat på Avbryt
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Fyll ComboBoxen med ikoner från bladet ICONS
    Dim ikoner As Range
    Set ikoner = Sheets("ICONS").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("ICONS").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    cmbIcon.List = ikoner.Value
    
    Call Pict(0)

End Sub

Private Sub InfogaIcon(ByVal bladNamn As String, ByVal iconNamn As String, ByVal skalningsfaktor As Double)
    ' Kopiera och centrera bilden från "ICONS"-arket till cell A7 på det valda bladet
    
    ' Hitta bildens celladress på "ICONS"-arket
    Dim wsIcons As Worksheet
    Set wsIcons = Sheets("ICONS")
    Dim intCell As Integer
    
    Dim bild As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set bild = wsIcons.Shapes(iconNamn)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If bladNamn = "Flik 1-5" Then intCell = 7
    If bladNamn = "Flik 1-10" Then intCell = 12
    If bladNamn = "Flik 1-15" Then intCell = 16
    If bladNamn = "Flik 1-20" Then intCell = 21
    If bladNamn = "Flik 1-31" Then intCell = 31
    If bladNamn = "Flik A-Ö" Then intCell = 21
    If bladNamn = "Flik 1-12" Then intCell = 13
    If bladNamn = "Flik Jan-Dec" Then intCell = 13
    
    If Not bild Is Nothing Then
        ' Kopiera bilden
        bild.Copy

        ' Klistra in bilden på det valda bladet
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets(bladNamn)
        ws.Pictures.Paste.Select
        
        ' Centrera och ändra storleken på bilden
        With Selection
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .ShapeRange.Width = ws.Cells(intCell, 1).Width * skalningsfaktor
            .ShapeRange.Height = ws.Cells(intCell, 1).Height * skalningsfaktor
            .Top = ws.Cells(intCell, 1).Top + (ws.Cells(intCell, 1).Height - .ShapeRange.Height) / 2
            .Left = ws.Cells(intCell, 1).Left + (ws.Cells(intCell, 1).Width - .ShapeRange.Width) / 2
        End With
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Rensa Urklipp
        ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select
    Else
        MsgBox "Ikonen '" & iconNamn & "' finns inte på bladet ICONS!", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sub Pict(n) hade trouble with getting the picture to load in to Me.imgBild.Picture.

I found a work around to this. I have to take the picture and paste it in to an empty chart then make a picture of that chart and save it in to a temp folder then i can use LoadPicture and get the picture to show on the userform as intended. I tried to use .SaveFile on the picture but it kept making it in to an  pfd file (pic.jpg.pdf).

This is the solution for the problem

```
Sub Pict(n)
    Dim Pic As Object
    Dim tempPath As String

    'check n for value
    If Me.cmbIcon.List(n) = "" Then Exit Sub
    'Show and activate woorksheet with pic and frame
    Worksheets("ICONS").Visible = True
    Sheets("ICONS").Activate
    PicName = Me.cmbIcon.List(n)
    ' Get pic in to frame export it as jpg and import it in to userform
    Blad9.Shapes(PicName).Copy
    Blad9.Shapes("PicFrame").Select
    Blad9.Select
        For Each Sh In ActiveChart.Shapes
           Sh.Delete
        Next
    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveChart.Shapes(PicName).Width = Blad9.Shapes("PicFrame").Width
    ActiveChart.Shapes(PicName).Height = Blad9.Shapes("PicFrame").Height
    tempPath = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & PicName & ".jpg"
    ActiveChart.Export tempPath
    Me.imgBild.Picture = LoadPicture(tempPath)
    'remove pick
    Kill tempPath
    Worksheets("ICONS").Visible = False

End Sub
```